# Turn off keyboard lights after typing

Tags: keyboard, power, backlight

I have my computer (MBP 2015) to turn the backlight on my keyboard off after I haven't used my computer for 10 seconds.

Is there a way how to disable the keyboard backlight after x amount of seconds of not typing?

Even though I know the 2015 MBP has good battery life, I would still like to do this to save a little bit of power.

Comment: Are you looking to set a shorter interval than 10 seconds? Does your keyboard backlight turn off after 10 seconds of not being used? If not, look here; http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/22/keyboard-illumination-locked-its-the-light-sensor/

Comment: @Rampant Yes my keyboard does turn off after 10 seconds. I would like it to turn off after 1 or 2 seconds if that is possible. Terminal default write command maybe?

Comment: I second that theory, and it may be found in a repository like this one: http://www.defaults-write.com/page/2/

Comment: @Rampant Cant find it in there with a simple search so it probably isn't in there. Probs because not that many people have asked for it! Lol